# How to access a matrix in an R application from the input $. I would like to display the table and plot confidence interval

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Here is the matrix.

```
  n.samples True.mean    pc5th   pc90th
1         4  6.055525 5.254145 6.799827
2         8  6.055525 5.486736 6.574188
```

Comment: Is that a matrix or a data.frame? If the data set is named `x`, what does `class(x)` return?

Answer (score 0):

In base R the confidence intervals for the mean given those sample sizes can be plotted as follws.

```
plot(True.mean ~ n.samples, data = x, 
     xlim = range(x[[1]] + c(-1, 1)), ylim = range(x[-1]))
arrows(x0 = x$n.samples, y0 = x$pc5th, y1 = x$pc90th, angle = 90, code = 3)
```

[image]

---

### Data

```
x <- read.table(text = "
  n.samples True.mean    pc5th   pc90th
1         4  6.055525 5.254145 6.799827
2         8  6.055525 5.486736 6.574188
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand better.
My problem was that I absolutely wanted to call my table in a reactive expression.

Comment: @Lili I have edited the question's tags to account for that. Added `reactive` and `shiny`.